# Google Verification Input errors

Tags: python, verification, google-search-console

I am following this tutorial on Moz:

https://moz.com/blog/how-to-get-search-console-data-api-python

and got to the stage where you have to authorise the account and part of the address bar into the script. However whatever I do gets me errors such as the the name of the code not being defined to the latest being

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I need to get this sorted and need your assistance

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephan765/Google-Search-Console-bulk-query/master/search_console_query.py this is the code that I am using

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using?

Comment: @etemple1 I have added the code that I am using